# passing node.js string to react front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I have this on node.js backend function:

```
    app.get('/returnTestValues', (req, res) => {
   
    var results = "hello friends"
    res.send(results);
})
```

then in front end, (react), I have this:

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Collapse = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'collpase navbar-collapse',
})``

const List = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
})``

const Item = styled.div.attrs({
    className: 'collpase navbar-collapse',
})``


// this.setState = { results: null };

fetch('http://localhost:3000/returnTestValues', {
  method: 'POST',
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log('response is: ' + response);
  response.json().then((results)=>this.setState({ results: results }))
  
}).then(results => {
    

   
    
    // let response = await response.json();
    this.setState({ results: results });
    console.log('results are' + results)
    

    

});

// function 



class Links extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
                {this.state.results}

                </Link>
                <Collapse>
                    <List>
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/movies/list" className="nav-link">
                                List Movies
                            </Link>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/movies/create" className="nav-link">
                                Create Movie
                            </Link>
                        </Item>
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


export default Links
```

above is the entire code to the entire file. Not a single line missing.
however, when I do this, it says:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

I am guessing maybe setState isn't defined from before, and it is not seeing it as something that can be used until I define it?

also, `console.log('response is: ' + response);` returns `[object Response]`

totally new to react, not sure how to do this. thanks for the help

Comment: Where you cann `this.setState` ?

Comment: what do you mean? @underscore

Comment: are you calling this in a class component ?

Comment: The problem is not evident from the code that you've posted. What matters is in what function that `fetch(..)` call is and how that function is invoked.

Comment: @underscore I have just edited my question to include the entire page worth of code

Comment: @Titus I've changed my question to show entire page of code.

Comment: you are calling the `setState` outside the component. that's unacceptable.

Comment: @underscore oh okay. How do I fix this? can u show me

Comment: Please find the answer

Answer (score 3):

Move your fetch to `componentDidMount` inside your class component

```
class Links extends Component {

 state = {
    results: []
 }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/returnTestValues', {
      method: 'POST',
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response is: ' + response);
        return response.json()

      }).then(results => {

        // let response = await response.json();
        this.setState({ results: results });
        console.log('results are' + results)
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
          {this.state.results}

        </Link>
        <Collapse>
          <List>
            <Item>
              <Link to="/movies/list" className="nav-link">
                List Movies
                            </Link>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Link to="/movies/create" className="nav-link">
                Create Movie
                            </Link>
            </Item>
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}


export default Links
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. When I change this now, it gives me this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null`. is it because it is not reading the string from my node.js code?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. i have done few updates

Comment: okay this loaded the page now, that worked! However, the `{this.state.results}` in the react code is returning empty, it is not showing up at all. and in the console, it is still logging `response is: [object Response]`.

Comment: Are you getting the data from your network tab?

Comment: when I try to log this: ` console.log('response is: ' + JSON.stringify(response));`, it returns this in the console. `{}`

Comment: open your inspect and check the network tab

Answer (score 0):

looks like `this` is not defined in that scope.  Try `async/await` paradigm instead:

```
let response = await response.json();
this.setState({ response });
```

Comment: where would I put this, and what would I remove?

Comment: Are you familiar with async/await?

Comment: yes, but not within my react / js code front end. not sure where it would fit into play within the code

Comment: Nevermind what I wrote. Now that you've posted more code, I see the problem.  You have to call `setState` within your React Component (inside the class). So you should put that fetch inside 'componentDidMount()`

Comment: so yes, referring to the answer the @underscore gave, that works, but I when I output it the same way to the screen `{this.state.results}` it seems to be empty. is there any reason for that maybe with the backend (node.js)?

Comment: It could be from the backend if your endpoint `http://localhost:3000/returnTestValues` isn't returning what you think it is

Answer (score 0):

Your state constructor should look like this so you can invoke the setState method

```
class Links extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          results: []
        };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">
                {this.state.results}

                </Link>
                <Collapse>
                    <List>
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/movies/list" className="nav-link">
                                List Movies
                            </Link>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/movies/create" className="nav-link">
                                Create Movie
                            </Link>
                        </Item>
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This also defines this as mentioned before

Comment: so in reference to your answer, `{this.state.results}` is still blank when I try to log it, and put it out to the screen. any ideas y?

Comment: Erm, not really. I do reccomend to use Postman or the Vscode extension called Thunder Client where you can  test every response from your server. Also as im only seeing this. You are sending a post request to the server that can, by your code above, only process GET requests. Try the method GET first, if still no answer, try Postman or Thunder Client.

Comment: Yeah I highly suspect it's that, since you post an empty object to the server which in return servers back the same empty object.

Comment: hmm okay, ig will have to give that a try then. I did change it to a post function in the node.js code, but it still returns this. so not sure what else to do there. thx 4 the help tho :)

Comment: Try the other way around, sorry if I was not being clear. So change your API call to this:

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/returnTestValues', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response is: ' + response);
        return response.json()

      }).then(results => {

        // let response = await response.json();
        this.setState({ results: results });
        console.log('results are' + results)
      });
  }

Comment: ohh okay. yeah it gave the same response, still empty. Wondering now if it maybe has to do with the way I am sending it to the client, maybe res.send isn't proper?